# Is it possible to change the default system font for a universal app? XCODE 6

Tags: ios, ipad, font-size

This is a very dumb question but I am not an expert in Objective-C so please forgive me if it is.

I would like to be able to change the default font size for my app based on the the screen size. I cannot find any way to set systemFontSize for an iPad to a different size than for an iPhone.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the size of the screen like this:

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
```

Then set the font size as a percentage of the screen size:

```
CGFloat fontScreenPercentage = 0.05f;
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(fontScreenPercentage * screenWidth)]
```

Comment: I want to change the default font size not create a custom font.

Comment: The default font size in what context exactly? Different app components  (UITableViewCell, UIButton) have different defaults. As far as I know though, there's no way to change the default system font sizes, they have to be changed programmatically (or in interface builder).

Comment: I was beginning to suspect that it is mission impossible. I really do not want to have to use IB to change every font size on text and buttons. It ought to be possible to change it programatically IMO. Thanks

Comment: You could use ios8 adaptive interface concept to align font size to screen size classes. If you create one label with this then you can copy it and have the defined sizes for the different screen sizes.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Comment: I'm trying to do this but when I attempt to create an adaptive font size the option for any-any is greyed out. And my primary concern is with buttons and text and I cannot copy them and use them without a lot of work (perhaps I do not understand what you are saying.)

Comment: I was using the wrong size class for ipads which explains why I was unable to set a font size.